# Can't run jsf2 project in Eclipse-Indigo/Tomcat7

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, jsf-2, tomcat7, eclipse-indigo

I've problem in properly setup a jsf2 project with tomcat.
Configuration:

- Eclipse Indigo x64 (IDE for Java EE developers)
- Tomcat 7.0.22 x64
- JDK 1.7.0
- JSF API: version 2.1.3
- JSF Implementation: Primefaces 3.0.M3
- Project facets: Dynamic Web module 3.0, Java 1.7, JavaScript 1.0, JavaServer Faces 2.0

I configure my tomcat v7.0 server in Eclipse, then add my project to the server, run tomcat from within Eclipse. 
Then, when I browse `localhost:8080/myapp`, Tomcat send me a 404 error. When I look in `<workspace-root>\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps` I see my webapp with all config files, namely web.xml, but it seems that Tomcat doesn't know it.
My web.xml file has the following web-app element configuration:

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
  xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"     
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
```

Moreover, when I start tomcat server, I see on the console view the usual output log string:
    Info: Initializing Mojarra 2.1.3 (FCS 20110908) for context '/mycontext'
so it seemed to me that all is configured fine.
What I'm missing?

Comment: Are you aware that `/myapp` is not the same as `/mycontext`? :) As to the concrete problem, what if you open a known file directly by its filename instead of relying on the `<welcome-file>`?

Comment: Sorry, sorry, sorry: my mistake! I misspelled index.html file: I wrote it "index html", with a space instead of period. Now all works as expected. 4 hours wasted!

Comment: Ah, my magic ball had it right :) I reposted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your `<welcome-file>` in `web.xml` is properly set and points to an existing file.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure about your eclipse setting file of named org.eclipse.wst.common.component is configured correctly.
I think it doesn't due to your tomcat server's setting.